# which algorithm is used in dji phantom 4 visual tracking

Tags: dji-sdk

I was wondering since Dji phantom 4 visual tracking is so good and up till now i have only heard KCF of give the best performance in tacking objects so does the Dji use the same algorithm in there drones.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an open source algorithm, it's DJIs own.

Comment: How do you know its their own?